# cacheable observable view in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does SQL Server provide any type of built-in approach for creating cacheable, observable views?

By "cacheable" I mean that after a view is selected once, SQL Server redirects subsequent selects against that view against a cached representation of that data instead of re-executing the underlying query.

By "observable" I mean that SQL Server will continue to select view results from cache until it detects that there have have been data changes in one of the underlying tables of the view query.

Comment: Query plans are cached and reused thus if you run the exact same, or similar enough query on a view it's likely to return results quicker with subsequent queries than the first. Perhaps this is where your question is focused, thought are materialized views which are another topic all together--but can increase query performance.

Comment: An indexed view behaves exactly as you want except for it is materialised when the index is created rather than at the time of the first SELECT. Apart from that SQL Server will ensure the pre calculated view results are kept in synch with the underlying data changes. But there are quite a few limitations on the queries for indexed views.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much describing how SQL Server works already. When you run a query to retrieve data from disk, it loads the data pages into the cache/buffer pool. Any subsequent queries against that data are read from the data pages in the cache. When you modify data on a page in the cache, it will write it back to disk.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337525(v=sql.105).aspx